# Helper Record not validated on compile

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Using Delphi 11.3 (including Patch 1).

I created a `Record Helper` for a custom `Variant` type.

My helper record is working, but the compiler doesn't validate my helper call on compile.

```
Type
  TTest = Type Variant;

  TTestHelper = Record Helper for TTest
  Public
    Function GetV: Variant;
    Function AsString: String;
  end;

{ TTestHelper }

function TTestHelper.GetV: Variant;
begin
  Result := Self;
end;

function TTestHelper.AsString: String;
begin
  Result := VarToStr(Self);
end;


//Simple button clik
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  V: TTest;
begin
  V := 'test';
  V := V.GetV; //Works as intended
  
  V := V.fopergkergprgkergtk4k3tp3gkg3p; //Compiles without any issue, but of course it gives an "Invalid Variant Operation" when I press the button.
end;
```

How can it be that the compiler compiles code that is obviously rubbish, and why is my Code Completion window not showing any of my methods (`GetV` and `AsString`)?

Comment: If I change Type Variant to Type String, then compiler capture that my V.fopergkergprgkergtk4k3tp3gkg3p is not valid. Is there a bug in the compiler when working with Variant ?

Comment: If you work with COM objects, you will call methods via the variant variable, which are only known at runtime. See [To call the methods of a dispatch interface] (https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Controlling_an_Automation_Server_Using_a_Dispatch_Interface)

Comment: Is that the reason the Code Completion (Ctrl+ Space) dosnt show any methode from my record helper because they are "unknown" at desgin time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can it be that the compiler compiles code that is obviously rubbish

That is a feature of `Variant`.

A `Variant` can contain different things, including an `IDispatch` interface to a COM object that "late-binds" to functions/properties at runtime instead of at compile-time.  A COM object might provide a `function fopergkergprgkergtk4k3tp3gkg3p` that may only be detectable at runtime, so the compiler allows everything after `.` on a `Variant` to compile, and it will be resolved at runtime, so it might succeed or fail at runtime.

Comment: That makes sense, do you know if this is also why the code completion (Ctrl + Space) at design time dosnt show any methode from my Record Helper ?

Comment: Not sure, can as well be a bug.

Comment: @HenrikLarsen Does Code Completion even recognize record helpers to begin with? Can you make helpers on other types and see them work as expected?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, for other helpers ist works as expected, but for Variant it fails.

Comment: It might be a bug or a feature specially for Variant, as other types does work fine.